# Directory.Exists(file) not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, directory

```
string sourcePath = GetValue(key); 

if (!Directory.Exists(@sourcePath))
{
    throw new Exception("Source path in does not exist");
}
```

In debug, looking at text visualizer for `sourcePath` returns location of file:

> C:\Users\John\Desktop\Sales.dat

This throws the exception even though I know the flie exists. I can see it on my desktop and if I paste C:\Users\John\Desktop\Sales.dat into an explorer, the file opens. Please advise.

Comment: Your path is pointing to a File, you need [`File.Exists`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Problem:** You are using the `Directory.Exists()` method to check whether a file exists or not.

**Solution:** You need to use the [File.Exists()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to check whether file exists or not.

FROM MSDN:

> **File.Exists()** Method Determines whether the specified file exists.

Try this:

```
if (!File.Exists(@sourcePath))
{
    throw new Exception("Source path in does not exist");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to know whether a file exists then File.Exists would probably be a better option than Directory.Exists, which tells you whether a directory exists or not.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to use `Directory.Exists()` you can do something like this:

```
if(!Directory.Exists(new FileInfo(sourcePath).DirectoryName))
{
    throw new Exception("Source path in does not exist");
}
```